# Limiting Case of Coin Toss Betting

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, gambling

Let $X_{n}$ be a random variable representing money that we have after n-th toss of a coin and $Y_{n}$ be random variable with Bernoulli distribution with probability of success (heads) $p \in ( \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2} )$. We play a game in which if we get the double of our money if we see heads and we lose half of our money if we see tails. Then: $$ X_{n+1} = 2X_{n} Y_{n+1} + \frac{1}{2} (1- Y_{n+1})X_{n} = ( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} Y_{n+1} ) X_{n}  $$

Let $X_{0} = 100$. Then we see that $EX_{n} = 100 ( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} p)^n$, so the expected value goes to infinity with $n$. Then we want to show that despite that $$ P( \{ \omega \in \Omega : \ \lim_{n \to \infty } X_{n} ( \omega ) = 0 \} ) = 1, \text{ i. e.} \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n} = 0 \ \text{a.s.}$$

Let $W_{n}$ represent the number of times we have seen heads. Then $W_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i} \Rightarrow  X_{n} = 100 \ 2^{ 2 n \overline{Y}_{n} - n }$. Let $ \varepsilon >0$ and then we see that $$ X_{n} > \varepsilon \iff 100 \ 2^{ 2 n \overline{Y}_{n} - n } > \varepsilon \iff e^{(2n \overline{Y}_{n} -n) \log 2)} > e^{ \log \frac{ \varepsilon}{100} } \iff 2n \overline{Y}_{n} -n > \frac{ \log \frac{ \varepsilon}{100}}{\log 2} \iff \overline{Y}_{n} > \frac{ \log \frac{ \varepsilon}{100}}{ 2 n \log 2} + \frac{1}{2} $$

Then because $p< \frac{1}{2}$ we have $ \overline{Y}_{n} > \frac{ \log \frac{ \varepsilon}{100}}{ 2 n \log 2} + p$, so $ P(X_{n} > \varepsilon )  =  P( \overline{Y}_{n} > \frac{ \log \frac{ \varepsilon}{100}}{ 2 n \log 2} + p)$. I think now I should use some form of Chebyshev inequality ,but I'm sort of stuck there.

Comment: We know that with prob 1, $\overline{Y}_n \rightarrow p$.  Since $p<1/2$, if  $\overline{Y}_n\rightarrow p$, then we know $\overline{Y}_n<1/2$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: So then $ \overline{Y}_{n} $cannot be greater than $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{ \log \frac{ \varepsilon }{ 100} }{ 2 n \log 2 }$ for sufficiently large $n$ because $ \frac{ \log \frac{ \varepsilon }{ 100} }{ 2 n \log 2 }$ goes to zero?

Comment: Yes, $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\log(\epsilon/100)}{2n\log(2)} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Then we know that for infinitely many $n$ it holds $ P( X_{n} > \varepsilon ) =0 $ which implies $ P( \limsup \{ X_{n} \leq \varepsilon \} ) = 1$. We know that  $ \limsup \{ X_{n} \leq \varepsilon \}$ is a subset of $  \{ \liminf X_{n} \leq \varepsilon \}$, so it is now true that $ \forall \varepsilon >0$ infinitely many times $ \liminf X_{n} \leq \varepsilon $, so $ X_{n} \to 0 $ a.s. Is that correct?

Comment: It is not correct to claim that "for infinitely many $n$ it holds $P[X_n>\epsilon]=0$." Consider the case $W_n = H/n$ where $H \sim N(0,1)$. Then $W_n\rightarrow 0$ with prob 1 but $P[W_n>\epsilon]>0$ for all $n$.

Comment: In general, if $P[A_n]=1$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ then $P[\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n] = 1$.  Define $A_n = \{(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |X_n|)>1/n\}$.